# What is deep sequencing?

Tags: ngs, covid-19, sars-cov-2

People talk about deep sequencing. Is there any way to calculate how deep the sequencing is ? What should be the optimum depth to get reliable data ?

I am doing whole genome sequencing of a virus genome which is 10 kb long. I got 80000 reads from Illumina sequencing. Is there any way to tell about my sequencing depth ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found [a post useful for this topic](http://www.metagenomics.wiki/pdf/definition/coverage-read-depth).

It explains the difference of coverage and depth.  It also has a useful explanation on how to calculate coverage and depth.

[image]

Here is a copy of what the link says just encase the post is removed:

> **Depth of coverage**
>
> *How strong is a genome "covered" by sequenced fragments (short reads)?*
>
> Per-base coverage is the average number of times a base of a genome is
>   sequenced. The coverage depth of a genome is calculated as the number
>   of bases of all short reads that match a genome divided by the length
>   of this genome. It is often expressed as 1X, 2X, 3X,... (1, 2, or, 3
>   times coverage).
>
> **Breadth of coverage**
>
> *How much of a genome is "covered" by short reads? Are there regions that are not covered, even not by a single read?*
>
> Breadth of coverage is the percentage of bases of a reference genome
>   that are covered with a certain depth. For example: 90% of a genome is
>   covered at 1X depth; and still 70% is covered at 5X depth.

## SAMtools: get breadth of coverage

Get breadth of coverage of a reference genome.

How many bases of my reference genome are covered by my short reads sample at a level of 5X or higher?

```
 # set shell variables to your file-names

 REF_GENOME_FILE=my_ref_genome.fna
 WGS_SAMPLE=my_short_read_sample.fastq 
 MIN_COVERAGE_DEPTH=5
```

1. Map short reads against reference genome (bowtie2)

   ```
   # create bowtie2 index database (database name: refgenome)

   bowtie2-build ${REF_GENOME_FILE} refgenome
   ls
   refgenome.1.bt2
   refgenome.2.bt2
   refgenome.3.bt2
   refgenome.4.bt2
   refgenome.rev.1.bt2
   refgenome.rev.2.bt2


   # map reads and sort bam file
   bowtie2 -x refgenome --no-unal -U ${WGS_SAMPLE} -S - -p 12 | \
   samtools view -bS - | \
   samtools sort -m 5G - mapping_result_sorted.bam

   -U ${WGS_SAMPLE} consider all reads as unpaired reads
   -S -             bowtie output in SAM format, write to standard out
   -x refgenome     use reference genome bowtie2-database
   --no-unal        suppress SAM records for reads that failed to align
   -p 12            use 12 processors
   ```
2. Get breadth of coverage (SAMtools)

   ```
   # create samtools index
   samtools index mapping_result_sorted.bam

   # get total number of bases covered at MIN_COVERAGE_DEPTH or higher
   samtools mpileup mapping_result_sorted.bam | awk -v 
   X="${MIN_COVERAGE_DEPTH}" '$4>=X' | wc -l
   32876

   # get length of reference genome
   bowtie2-inspect -s refgenome | awk '{ FS = "\t" } ; BEGIN{L=0}; {L=L+$3}; 
   END{print L}'
   45678
   ```

Result: breadth of reference genome coverage
total number of covered bases: 32876  (with >= 5X coverage depth)
Depth of coverage (average per-base coverage): 0.719 X (32876 ÷ 45678) (total number of covered bases divided by reference genome length)
percent: 71.9%  (0.719 × 100) (coverage breadth in percent)

Comment: Nice picture! Could you include the relevant parts of the linked page in the answer to make the answer self sustained (and avoid having to go one link further).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Samantha. This exactly answers my question.

Answer (score 9):

There are several questions in your post I'll try to answer each one:

> Is there any way to calculate how deep the sequencing is ?

See gringer's [answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2727/48). TLDR: The depth of the sequencing is how many times each position has been sequenced.

> What should be the optimum depth to get reliable data ?

The optimum depth depends on what you want to do with that data. Usually,  30X or 50X is done, but in targeted sequencing you can sequence a lot more reaching 1000X (which would be really deep).

> Is there any way to tell about my sequencing depth ?

If you know the length of the region sequenced and how many bases you have in the reads, you can calculate the general sequencing depth.

Answer (score 8):

Sequencing depth is typically calculated as the *number of total bases sequenced* divided by the *number of bases in the target genome*. An Illumina sequencing run with 2x125 bp reads and 500 million read pairs sequenced would be a sequencing depth of about 40X (assuming my calculations are correct for a 3 billion base genome).

The sequencing depth depends on how long each read is, as well as whether it is a paired-end sequencing run. 80,000 read pairs with each having 125 bp would be a coverage of 2000X for a 10 kbp viral genome (assuming the sample were entirely composed of that virus).

The optimum depth changes depending on the application. A genotyping-by-sequencing analysis, combined with imputation, could work well with 96 samples at a 1X coverage (or possibly less). On the other end of the scale, a cell-free DNA analysis to identify structural variation in metastasing cancer may need a few thousand times coverage of the host DNA.